# Creating a typed array column from an empty array

Tags: arrays, apache-spark

I just want to solve the following problem: i want to filter out all tuples of a data frame in which the strings contained in one column are not contained in a blacklist which is given as a (potentially empty) array of strings.

For example: if the blacklist contains "fourty two" and "twenty three", all rows are filtered out from the dataframe in which the respective column contains either "fourty two" or "twenty three".

The following code will successfully execute, if the `blacklist` is not empty (for example Array("fourty two")) and fail else (Array.empty[String]):

```
//HELPERs
val containsStringUDF = udf(containsString(_: mutable.WrappedArray[String], _: String))
def containsString(array: mutable.WrappedArray[String], value: String) = {array.contains(value)}

def arrayCol[T](arr: Array[T]) = {array(arr map lit: _*)}

df.filter(!containsStringUDF(arrayCol[String](blacklist),$"theStringColumn"))
```

The error message is:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(array(), theStringColumn)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array<string> type, however, 'array()' is of array<null> type
```

It seems, that empty arrays appear typeless to spark. Is there a nice way to deal with this?

Comment: so blacklist is an array ? Actually I4m not very sure what you are trying to do

Comment: Yes, eliasah. It contains strings which i do not want in column "theStringColumn" to appear.

Comment: can you give an example please ? (input, blacklist and expected output)

Comment: Sure, I added an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overthinking a problem. What you really need here is `isin`:

```scala
val blacklist = Seq("foo", "bar")

$"theStringColumn".isin(blacklist: _*)
```

Moreover don't depend on the local type for `ArrayType` being a `WrappedArray`. Just use `Seq`.

Finally to answer your question you can either:

```scala
array().cast("array<string>")
```

or:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType, StringType}

array().cast(ArrayType(StringType))
```

Comment: Thank you! The kind of solution I was looking for was casting. Somehow i missed that. Also thank you for the tip regarding the use of Seq. I will try that.